# Remove unwanted part of permalink custom structure from CPT url?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

My site currently has regular posts (in a section called "Trend Watch"), as well as a Custom Taxonomy (called "Region").

My permalink settings have this Custom Structure:

```
/trend-watch/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

which gives me these urls:

- `/trend-watch/regions/`  (lists all terms in the Regions taxonomy)
- `/trend-watch/regions/europe/`  (lists all posts with the term
  "europe" in the Regions taxonmy).
- `/trend-watch/2011/03/an-interesting-article/`  (a single post).

But now i'm adding a new Custom Post Type, called Reports. When registering this CPT, I set `rewrite => array('slug' => 'reports')`. But the urls are including "trend-watch/" first:

```
/trend-watch/reports/some-report/
```

How can I remove "trend-watch/" from the Reports CPT urls, but keep it for regular Posts (and the associated Custom Taxonomies).

Comment: FYI - You should take a moment to mark @prettyboymp's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the 'with_front' parameter in the rewrite argument for the custom post type to false.

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'reports', 'with_front' => false)
```